# Performance Issue while using joining multiple df

Tags: performance, join, pyspark

I have a code which tries to do left join with multiple data frames as the attributes getting built from each of these data frames are to be positioned at different places in the final json file that I’m trying to write. Also the code is to grow as and when the new elements are getting added. Using the current approach , the code is taking almost 3-4 hours and finally aborts due to performance issue.
What is the better way to address this performance issue?
Lkp_df1
lkd_df2 etc
Main_df = main_df.join(keys,’left’)
.select( ....)
is the pattern I have in code

Answer (score 0):

Please paste your entire code . Try to use persist or checkpoint and also check for number of partitions and data distribution across cluster

Comment: ALOK , the code is very big to be pasted here but pretty much follows what I said above , it has multiple data frames . It gets joined with main frame via a left join and gets added to main frame. 
Is there any alternate way to achieve this other than join operator? 
If no what is the way the code can be optimised.